# how to define hibernate.c3p0 connection Pool in wildfly 10 standalone.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have a issue of connection drop with the Mysql DB after a long idle Time i.e. I get different types of errors including "maximum Packet Allowed Size" error, "Last Packet recieved 8499970 milliseconds ago" error etc. 
I am Using Hibernate-JPA with the JPA version 2.0

Currently The datasource Configuration in my Wildfly standalone.xml is:

```
<datasources>

                <datasource jndi-name="java:/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opera</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysqlDriver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>admin</user-name>
                        <password>admin</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>

                    <driver name="mysqlDriver" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

The persistence.xml file looks Like this:

```
 <persistence version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="metadatatool-persistence">
         <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
                <!-- Hibernate properties -->
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />


                <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="600" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="2000" />
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="30" />
                <property name="hibernat.c3p0.automaticTestTable" value="conTestTable" />
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

I have included the c3p0-4.1.1-final Jar in my project but it looks like it is not working I am still getting no connection error after Idle time, and I can't find a proper step by step solution anywhere

**EDIT**

I have defined another property in my persistence.xml I dont Know if It will work or not

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1:3306/opera?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true;reconnectAtTxEnd=true;autoReconnectForPools=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
```

**EDIT Update**
I Used the above defined properties and I didn't got the connection error now, however I did found a ERROR in the Log file which is below, the deployment is working fine though

```
error is:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session not found BDnAhOKBakcD8h9izG1Dembs0DFHWwWgYFVYPEKm
```

Also the connection String I used in this property is this the right approach ? What side-effects can I face ?

Comment: Why you use xa-datasource-class since you dont use xa-datasource and have just one persistence-unit?

Comment: This is the setting I found on one of their docs about how to define your data source in wildfly, another step of this was to put the MySqlConnectorJ under "Modules" directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to configure your own connection pool implementation (such as c3po) in any full Java EE implementation, such as WildFly/JBoss EAP, WebSphere, GlassFish, etc.

All of these servers provide you with connection pool implementations and management tools to configure them.

In WildFly you can set this up with your DataSource configuration in the management console or use the CLI. See [WildFly 10 DataSource configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration).

You should be able to reduce your persistence.xml to:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="metadatatool-persistence">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I left the SQL generation properties there for convenience, although they're not necessary when `false` all of the time.

After this you need to ensure that your DataSource is configured correctly.

```
<datasource jta="true" 
            jndi-name="java:/MySQLDS"
            pool-name="MySQLDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opera</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver> mysqlDriver </driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>admin</user-name>
        <password>admin</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker
            class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter
            class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

Note the connection validation configuration that you have missing. This was added for free when the DataSource was set up through the admin console.

*You should never modify the standalone.xml file by hand.*

Comment: But when I deploy it on a server then after in-activity of about 8 hours the Connection to database is turned off by itself, and when I searched about it, I only found that Hibernate's connection pooling  isn't for production neither for the performance testing  and that I shoudl use a  third party connection pooler one of them is C3p0.  Am I doing something wrong then, in my datasource?

Comment: The solution above is not using "Hibernate connection pooling"; it is using the connection pool implementation provided by WildFly. WildFly is your "third party connection pooler". You might use something like c3po in *old* versions of Tomcat, which had a kind of sucky connection pool implementation of its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/MySQLDS"/>
```

And then use the datasource in your persistence context like that:

```
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
```

Have a look at [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

Comment: But where to define the hibernate.c3p0 ? they didn;t work by defining them in persistence.xml , also I am not using spring frame work. Is there a specific setting fro hibernate.c3p0 in Wildfly 10 ???

Comment: Do not know... But I see you do not have the datasource in your persistence.xml

Comment: Try adding <jta-data-source>java:/MySQLDS</jta-data-source> before properties

Comment: It was already in my file I missed it while adding it in the question How-ever I have added it now also My Entities are included in the persistence.xml they are too many So I haven't included them in the question.. The issue is after a long idle time around 6-8 hours the connection to database is closed by itself. it works fine when using normally

Comment: You can add the code below to reconnect if connection suddenly drops

Comment: <validation>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
     </validation>

Comment: Moreover you can add pool configuration. something like  <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <prefill>false</prefill>
                    </pool>

Comment: Already Tried that but it didn't worked out as well ( dont know why ) So, I removed it.